# What is the correct use of "to and for"?

Tags: for

What is the correct question."Do you want to buy the dress tomorrow for you mom? or Do you want to buy the dress tomorrow to your mom? - 
What is the correct sentence? tks

Answer (score 1):

The correct one is "Do you want to buy the dress tomorrow for you mom?" when you are talking about providing something to someone or something you always use the word for.

Comment: so, when can I use "to"?tks

Comment: I was not exactly right with this providing concept but you need to use 'for' in this sentence. A correct way of using 'to' in a sentence would be something like "I will go and buy a dress tomorrow. I will give it to my mom.".

Answer (score 0):

The first one is correct. "Do you want to buy the dress tomorrow for your mom" means **you are asking if your mom wants to buy the dress**. (**see the second use of for below.**)

***To* is a preposition. Also, It is used as part of the infinitive. Let me explain the use of **to** a little.

1) We can use to as a preposition to indicate a destination or direction: **Example:** We are going ***to*** London. To in the example was used to indicate the destination. You can also use ***to*** for direction.

2) We use *to* with verbs such as give, send, write, to indicate the person or thing that receives or experiences the object of the verb: **Example:** I gave the letters ***to*** my mother.

3) We use ***to*** before a verb to make the ***to*** infinitive form: **Example:** I need ***to*** wake up early tomorrow.

Use of **For**

1) We use ***for*** to talk about a purpose or a reason for something: **Example**:  I am going for a lunch.

2) We frequently use ***for*** to introduce the person or people receiving something: **Example**: I bought a pen **for** my father.

3) We use ***for*** with a period of time to refer to duration: **Example**: There is an amazing beach. I usually go there **for** a couple of hours at the weekends.

Those examples do not demonstrate all use of ***to*** and ***for***, but you can conclude the main idea. As a result, your